# Maxent and spatialMaxent not producing prediction maps

Tags: maxent

I am running (from the GUI) Maxent version 3.4.4 and spatialMaxent, both with jdk-18.0.2.1_windows-x64_bin.

Both programs run successfully, yet none of them produces the ascii files for the predictions.

The option 'Make pictures of predictions' in the main GUI window is ticked (Cloglog/ascii selected).

Thank you for any suggestions

paola